# Disable the page start only for a particular page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-framework-version

I am using .net 4.0 framework (using razor) and i have a file _PageStart.cshtml in my source folder and it gets used by every file as it is supposed to. I however have one file index.cshtml, where i dont want this start up to run.

Is there a way to disable a page from using the page start?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the following code in _PageStart.cshtml file works

```
@if (@Request.RawUrl != "index.cshtml"){
    <code here>
}
```

However please let me know if there is a better way like editing something in index.cshtml file